# Astronomy Camera rapidly disconnects when used on Ubuntu

Tags: usb

For the past while I've been trying to connect my Celestron Nightscape Camera to my Ubuntu system. This specific camera (with a KAI-10100 CCD) does not have a driver, but there is a similar model which has an open-source driver which I'd like to modify. Unfortunately, I've been having some issues getting the camera to fully connect to my system.

I should note first that this is likely not a physical (port/cable) issue, as I am able to connect with the same cable to my MacOS laptop. Anyways, here's what's happening: I connect the camera, it momentarily connects long enough to transfer USB idVendor as well as product and manufacturer strings, then it disconnects. This happens fast enought that  I haven't been able to get an lsusb output with the camera present. Here's a copy of the dmesg terminal output for the full sequence:

```
[ 7556.560374] usb 3-13: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[ 7556.711985] usb 3-13: New USB device found, idVendor=19b4, idProduct=0065, bcdDevice= 7.00
[ 7556.711990] usb 3-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 7556.711992] usb 3-13: Product: Nightscape CCD Camera
[ 7556.711994] usb 3-13: Manufacturer: Celestron
[ 7556.861701] usb 3-13: USB disconnect, device number 14
```

I've also used usbmon and dumpcap to capture the USB traffic between the camera and my system. I've attached a Wireshark capture file, as well as a screenshot of the top-level packet overview for quick reference:
[image: Wireshark review screen]

Finally, here's a little info about the camera and the steps I've already taken. The main processor is a Lattice FPGA (ECP2 7FN256C-6I), but the USB chip is a FTDI FT2232HL. I've removed the brlTTY package, as I know that can cause issues.

I'd really appreciate some help with this issue, as the camera has a pretty nice chip, despite Celestron's ineptitude when it comes to software.

Comment: Frequent disconnects are often a sign of a bad cable with a high impedance. Try using a different cable. Yeah, I've read that it works under MacOS but Linux has a different USB stack.

Comment: I’ve done this, no change - also, the config data is never corrupted either, which points me even further in the direction of software issue.

Comment: Try the latest available kernel, e.g. 5.9.14 or even 5.10-rc7

Comment: Usually that happens when the hardware waits for something to enable it. Some phones for example will boot, show a tty for a few seconds and then disconnect. The main task of the driver is to connect right away and do *something* (it could be a firmware upload) to activate the hardware. If I were you, I'd add the exact model of your camera and also the model and location of the open source driver for the other camera. Somebody with driver writing experience might be able to suggest something to port it.